# How to tell Microsoft Word to not check spelling and grammar within quotation marks?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a book in which the characters use a lot of slang. Microsoft Word keeps on marking grammar and spelling mistakes in dialogue, and it's getting kind of annoying. I do, however, want to see spelling and grammar corrections for normal text (not within quotes). **How do I tell Microsoft Word to ignore spelling and grammar within quotation marks?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do by marking all such text as "Do not check spelling or grammar" :

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. In the dialog, ensure that the cursor is in the **Find what** field
3. Click the **More>>** button
4. Click **Use wildcards**
5. Enter in the field `"*"` (ensure that the quotes are the same as used in the text)
6. Click inside the **Replace with** field
7. Click the **Format** drop-down list and choose **Language...**
8. Click on **Do not check spelling or grammar**
9. Click on **Replace All** (if 0 changes are reported - check your quotes)
10. Done. Click **Cancel**.

For the changes to be visible, recheck grammar or simply close and re-open the document. Also, take a backup of the document before starting, and afterward check the
text following the last quote, in case you had an unpaired quote floating around.

[image]