# Microsoft Word Remove Proofing for a single Document

Tags: microsoft-word, proofing

I'm currently using MS Word to create resumes in my job search. In the skills section, there's a bunch of bullet points. The convention is not to put periods at the end of each point, but this causes Word to put a blue underline under the last word of each bullet point, because there's a missing period.

[image]

My solution is to go into Options -> Proofing and then check both boxes at the bottom to remove proofing for the document.

[image]

My question is when other people open these MS Word documents on their own computers, will the proofing for the document still be disabled for them, or will they have the blue underlines appear even though I disabled them on my own computer.

If they still have the proofing, how can I make it so they don't after I send them the document? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell Microsoft Word to not check spelling and grammar within quotation marks?](https://superuser.com/questions/1130251/how-to-tell-microsoft-word-to-not-check-spelling-and-grammar-within-quotation-ma)

Answer (score 0):

The proofing depends on each individual's settings. There is no way to modify another user's Word settings. It's like with the dictionaries, if a word doesn't exist and you add it in your own dictionary on Word, it won't be in another individual's Word dictionary.

Besides, if they enable editing, for example, and that their language locale is different from yours, the whole content will be underlined in red, THEY will need to select all and change it to the language of the document.

If you don't want them to see those, you need to export your file to another file format such as PDF. You can do it in "File", "export to PDF", or you can do it using the "Print" function and change your printer to PDF, or you can also find many Word to PDF tools online. Hope this helped!

Comment: Good analysis, but it is possible. See my answer.

Comment: Ah, what a trick! In the OP's example, it's fine, but I wonder what the implications would be when working with other collaborators on the same Word files...

Comment: Take a look at the links at the end of the answer. You are right about implications. Many people feel like this formatting is a virus because it travels with the text. I use the character style and use it for legal citations. The danger is that it is virtually invisible and can be pasted with the text unless the paste is text only.n My character style also includes Italics so it is more easily spotted if it is somewhere it is not supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question: Your proofing settings for the document or for Word will not apply on a different computer. *However, you can apply special formatting that will.*

### Apply the "Do not check spelling or grammar" setting to all text in the document.

1. Select all of the text in your document (Ctrl+A on a Windows machine).
2. Go to the Review tab.
3. Under Language, click on Proofing Language.
4. Check the box for "do not check spelling or grammar."

This change sticks with text (often causing problems). It is a character-level setting, not a document setting. You can do this just to the problem areas or text, not only to the whole document. You can even create a character style to apply the setting. Here are two web pages that examine this:

- [Mastering the Spelling Checker](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/MasterSpellCheck.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, Word MVP
- [Spelling Checker Does Not Work - Solutions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b?tm=1579788821357) *(my article on the Microsoft site)*